# form around jquery dialog button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dialog

I'm just wondering if it's possible to put a form around a button in a **jQuery dialog**. I've looked around and tried it myself in the `JavaScript` I'm using but can't seem to get it to work. If possible, I want it around the button *"View Unread"* as I need to pass something to the next page by a form.

I would post a picture but my rep isn't high enough:

Here is my code:

```
$("#notifiedDiv").dialog({
     resizable: true,
     height: 300,
     width: 400,
     autoopen: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
         "View unread": function () {

         },
             "Ok": function () {

         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bossible but I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead do this

```
"View unread": function () {
    $.ajax({
    url:"the action url"
    data: {"name": "value" } /*key values like name+values of your forms input*/
    success:function(data) {
      /*do something with the response*/
    }
    });
},
```

[Check here more info about ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Include form in dialog `div` without button and link dialog button to this form:

```
"View unread": function () {
    $("#notifiedDiv form").submit();
},
```